# How can I combine multiple rows into one row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, union, pivot

So I have looked all day to find a good solution to this problem, and have come up empty. Let's say I have a table similar to this:

ProjectID       Position     BilledSoFar     NotBilled 
----------------------------------------------------
EE123             AA1               100                          200 
EE456              MNGR          4000                       500 
EE123              AA3                43                             0 
EE012              SPEC1          435                         4355 
....                    ....                  ....                          ....

And what I am attempting to do is to take multiple rows with the same projectID, and combine all of these rows into one. I need the "Position" "BilledSoFar" and "NotBilled" for each project ID, EVEN IF Position doesn't exist for a ProjectID,  like so:
     

ProjectID

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EE123             AA1          100          200          AA3          43          0          MNGR          Null          Null        ..............

And so on.

So I need to put all records for the given project ID into one row, and even if a position doesn't exist for that projectID (the example above is MNGR, which isn't a position under EE123) I have to have all positions and the billing info (which will obviously be NULL if that Position doesn't exist for the projectID). I've tried pivot, joins, and considered a union but still can't figure this out, and I'm running out of guesses here.

I should also note that I know there are a fixed number of projectids (let's say 3400) and there are a fixed number of Positions (let's say 20 for this one).

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how many positions you have per projectID?

Comment: While you could make this work if you knew all of the ProjectIDs before-hand, and the number of them was fixed, I'm guessing that's not the case. In general, this is not the sort of thing that sql is meant to do. I'd suggest retrieving the multiple rows, and then assembling them in your application, whether that be a 'client' application, or worst case, in a stored proc.

Comment: Hey guys, to answer your questions: eaolson - We do know how many positions, there are about 20 altogether. Justin - We use SQL Server. Grey- Yeah and that's why it is such a pain that this task was passed on to me. I would do them manually but there are thousands of projects that would need this. I do know all of that projectids as well. I've done a select distinct to retrieve each seperate one, it's just getting data to behave this way that is the trick. This is a one time thing I need to do to generate a report so if I can get it to work on the data just once I'm good. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE to flatten this out, however this would not put the values into separate columns, but instead put them in one comma delimited column. If that does not work for you:

- You could use a very complex creation of dynamic SQL to perform the next option on the fly (it will only create the number of columns that are needed (if building out to 20 is not needed)
- You can hardcode a very long left join since you know that you will have no more than 20 rows and only need this once:

It would look something like this:

```
SELECT ProjectID, Position, BilledSoFar, NotBilled, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProjectID ORDER BY Position) AS RowNum
INTO #ProjectTable
FROM ProjectTable

SELECT ProjectTable.ProjectID, 
    ProjectTable.Position AS Position1, ProjectTable.BilledSoFar AS BilledSoFar1, 
    ProjectTable.NotBilled AS NotBilled1, 
    ProjectTable2.Position AS Position2, ProjectTable2.BilledSoFar AS BilledSoFar2, 
    ProjectTable2.NotBilled AS NotBilled2, 
    ...
    ProjectTable20.Position AS Position20, ProjectTable20.BilledSoFar AS BilledSoFar20, 
    ProjectTable20.NotBilled AS NotBilled20 
FROM #ProjectTable AS ProjectTable
    LEFT JOIN #ProjectTable AS ProjectTable2
        ON ProjectTable.ProjectID = ProjectTable2.ProjectID AND ProjectTable2.RowNum = 2
    ...
    LEFT JOIN #ProjectTable AS ProjectTable20
        ON ProjectTable.ProjectID = ProjectTable20.ProjectID AND ProjectTable20.RowNum = 20
WHERE ProjectTable.RowNum = 1
```

- As suggested, this SHOULD be done in a client application, but if it is only done once, then I would go with the easy copy and paste method that I posted above

Answer (score 0):

You could create a procedure which accepts the desired projectID as argument.

Use a CURSOR (http://justgeeks.blogspot.com/2008/08/using-t-sql-cursor-in-sql-server.html)
to loop through the rows matching the projectID to build a delimited string of the fields.

Return the string or build a select statement from the string and execute it.

For example selection string to execute built from CURSOR:

```
SELECT 'EE123' AS 'ProjectID',
       'AA1', 
       '100', 
       '200', 
       'AA3', 
       '43', 
       '0', 
       'MNGR', 
       'Null', 
       'Null' 
FROM <tablaname> 
WHERE 1=1
```